# Showing that $I+tA$ is invertible using $f(t)=\det(I+tA)$

Tags: matrices, analysis

Let $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ a square matrix with $\text{trace}(A) \neq 0$. I would like to show that $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$,

$$f(t)=\det(I+tA)$$

local while $t=0$ is invertible.

Comment: Okay and what's your question?

Comment: I think he wants to prove that there is $\varepsilon>0$ so that $f$ becomes invertible when restricted to $(-\varepsilon, \varepsilon)$.

Comment: @ZacharySelk Question is how to show that f is invertible

Comment: @Melina You mean $I+tA$ is invertible, not $f$.

Comment: What does "$\,f\,$ is **local** " mean ?

Comment: It is difficult to understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not entirely clear what you are asking.

If $\lambda_k$ are the eigenvalues of $A$, we see that
$f(t) = \prod_k (1+t \lambda_k)$ and hence
$f'(t) = \sum_i \lambda_i \prod_{k\neq i} (1+t \lambda_k)$. Then $f'(0) = \sum_i \lambda_i = \operatorname{tr} A \neq 0$.

The implicit function theorem shows that $f$ is locally invertible.

Comment: I think your answer fits better the OP 'question'. Please, would you like to edit the OP question accordingly? Maybe it would be better that I delete my answer... Thanks.

Comment: @OlivierOloa: No need to delete your answer...

Answer (score 2):

**Hint**. The function $f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ is *continuous*, thus 
$$
f(0)\neq0 \implies \text{there is $\,\varepsilon>0$ such that}\, \left.f(t)\frac{}{}\right|_{t \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)}\neq0,
$$ thus $I+tA$ is invertible for $t \in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$.